# How to download videos from Coursera with curl?

Tags: curl

Downloading videos from [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) is not as easy as copy and pasting the link in terminal. I also have tried [exporting](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lopabhfecdfhgogdbojmaicoicjekelh) cookies from my browser in `cookie.txt` file and doing a:

```
curl --cookie cookie.txt "https://class.coursera.org/comnetworks-2012-001/lecture/download.mp4?lecture_id=37"
```

as suggested in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/161778/49715) but that produces a file named `download.mp4?lecture_id=37` with nothing in it.

Can somebody tell me how can I download those video lectures? because downloading them with browser is a risk (I have a slow connection and if by chance if some error occurs my too much time is wasted in re-downloading it).

Comment: Maybe you have to specify the user-agent of your request via the `--user-agent <agent string>` switch. A common `<agent string>` is `Mozilla/5.0`.

Comment: @user1146332 I already have `--user-agent` set in my `~/.curlrc` file (the user agent of the browser I am using).

Answer (score 2):

As with any web service, the exact method changes a lot.

In the [coursera-dl](https://github.com/coursera-dl/coursera) project, we try to do all the magic. The code involves jumping through some redirects and keeping cookies in place (which changes almost at every login), but you can run it with the `--debug` option to see how it calls `curl` or `wget` or your preferred downloader.

Disclaimer: I am a contributor to the project.

Answer (score 1):

The Server responds with the status code `302` that is the requested URI moved temporarily.

If you look into the header of the http-response with

```
curl -i --cookie cookie.txt <URL>
```

and there is a valid `location` given, curl doesn't redo the request for this new location by default. To get `curl` doing this, you have to add the `-L` switch to the command line.

So

```
curl -L --cookie cookie.txt <URL>
```

should do the job.

---

Just a note: If you had used `wget` instead of `curl` you wouldn't have faced what you've described.

Comment: Are you sure that works? I'm still getting `download.mp4?lecture_id=37` with curl by the method you described. wget also doesn't helps much, wget is outputing `welcome?type=logout&visiting=%2Fcomnetworks-2012-001%2Flecture%2Fdownload.mp4?lecture_id=37`

Comment: It definitely works. I downloaded the video both with `curl` and `wget`. It looks like your session was finalized in the meanwhile and you have to get a new valid cookie.

Comment: What's your `~/.curlrc` file? or what are passing additional to curl?

Comment: without a `~/.curlrc` `curl -L --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0"  --cookie <COOKIE> -o <FILE> <URL>` works for me (just tried it again for a second)

Comment: I get [this output](http://pastebin.com/FpkZvDk4).

Comment: More revealing would be if you post what `curl -i --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0" --cookie cookie.tx <URL>` yields. You can find my output [here](http://pastebin.com/As0nUqJ1) (the "real" location of the video is in the Line beginning with `Location:`)

Comment: I get [this output](http://pastebin.com/7zFw1GNd) of header.

Comment: Have you saved all cookies that the site created and merged them into `cookie.txt`?

Comment: It would be better if you explain what are `-i` and `-L` means

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Dhulkee Coursera. It's a gui based application made specially to batch download videos from Coursera.org. Try it ou: http://dhulkeecoursera.blogspot.com.br/2014/02/dhulkee-coursera-has-gone-open-source.html